# On graceful signal, nginx throws Connection refused when trying to connect to uWSGI socket

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

This problem is perplexing me, because I seem to be following everything within the docs that would allow for a graceful restart.

I am running uWSGI in Emperor mode, with a bunch of vassals. When I try to do a graceful restart of one of the vassals, I receive an nginx `502 Bad Gateway` response for about half a second. Here's some information:

One of my vassal .ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
processes = 2
home = /var/www/.virtualenvs/www.mysite.com
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock.myapp
pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi.pid.myapp
module = myapp
pythonpath = /var/www/www.mysite.com/mysite
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/myapp.log
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
gid = www-data
uid = www-data
```

Then, I want to gracefully restart this process:

```
kill -HUP `cat /tmp/uwsgi.pid.myapp`
```

The output from the vassal log file looks alright (I think?)

```
...gracefully killing workers...
Gracefully killing worker 1 (pid: 29957)...
Gracefully killing worker 2 (pid: 29958)...
binary reloading uWSGI...
chdir() to /var/www/www.mysite.com/vassals
closing all non-uwsgi socket fds > 2 (max_fd = 1024)...
found fd 3 mapped to socket 0 (/tmp/uwsgi.sock.kilroy)
running /var/www/.virtualenvs/www.mysite.com/bin/uwsgi
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 15) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from kilroy.ini
open("/var/log/uwsgi/kilroy.log"): Permission denied [utils.c line 250]
unlink(): Operation not permitted [uwsgi.c line 998]
*** Starting uWSGI 1.2.3 (64bit) on [Fri Jun  8 09:15:10 2012] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 01 June 2012 09:56:19
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /var/www/www.mysite.com/vassals
writing pidfile to /tmp/uwsgi.pid.kilroy
detected binary path: /var/www/.virtualenvs/www.mysite.com/bin/uwsgi
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi.sock.kilroy fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 23:04:22)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Set PythonHome to /var/www/.virtualenvs/www.mysite.com
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x19e3e90
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
added /var/www/www.mysite.com/gapadventures/ to pythonpath.
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x19e3e90 pid: 30041 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 30041)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 30042, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 30043, cores: 1)
```

But when I try to access the site quickly after this, my nginx log gets this result:

```
2012/06/08 09:44:43 [error] 5885#0: *873 connect() to unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock.kilroy failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.100.50.137, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock.kilroy:", host: "mydomain.com"
```

This happens for about half a second after sending the signal, so this is clearly not very graceful.

Any advice? Thanks so much!

Comment: experiencing a similar problem. current theory is that while uwsgi is busy doing its reloading, it is ignoring/refusing connections from nginx...

Answer (score 0):

Correct sockets path in nginx config and uWSGI. Sockt have to be identical

Was

```
unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock.kilroy
```

or

```
/tmp/uwsgi.sock.myapp
```

Need:

nginx

```
unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock.myapp
```

and

uwsgi

```
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock.myapp
```